# How to call publishInstall() in facebook graph api android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to call

```
publishInstall();
```

In my application. When application is starting, I am using facebook graph api.

Comment: Are you using the Facebook SDK? There's a publishInstallAsync in the Settings class.

Comment: no it is graph api i have put some classes in my graph api in my application but can i use in my graph api or any other way to use it pls help

Comment: The easiest way is to use the SDK. This is because you need to get an attribution id which the Facebook app provides you, and the SDK does that for you.

Comment: but Ming Li can i do that with the help of graph api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added facebook.jar in my project and just call above method from Setting.java

```
Settings.publishInstall(getApplicationContext(), "FACEBOOK_APP_ID");
```

Comment: Yes now i have got it without above solution or intregat no other solution i have follow Facebook developer blogs thanks for your attenstions thanks